# Spearmans rank with ties in pascal

Tags: pascal, freepascal, lazarus, turbo-pascal

I'm working on a project where I need to calculate the spearman's rank of some data, Currently my program can calculate the spearmans rank as long as their are no tied rankings. I would use an existing unit but I need to display the ranked values in a string grid, alongside their rank, not just the Spearmans value itself. I'm having trouble coming up with a solution that allows the tied values ranks to be averaged to allow the test to be calculated when there is tied data.
Thanks you for your time.

[here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spearman%27s_rank_correlation_coefficient) is the Spearmans rank

This is the code I have so far, this only sorts and ranks the values, the actual spearmans value is calculated in another procedure

```
type Tspearman = record
                          x : string;
                          y : string;
                          xrank : string;
                          yrank : string;
                          d : string;
                          d2 : string;
                    end;


procedure TForm1.SortRank();
var
  s:string;
  P2, P2plus1,q : single;
   Position_1, Position_2,i: Integer;
   Temporary : TSpearman;
   t:string; 
begin
   for Position_1 := 1 to ListBoxSP.Items.Count-1 do //Length(data) - 1 do
   begin
      for Position_2 := 1 to ListBoxSP.Items.Count-2 do //( Length( data ) - 2 ) do
      begin
           P2 := StrToFloat(data[ Position_2 ].x);
           P2plus1 := StrToFloat(data[ Position_2 + 1 ].x );
         if P2 > P2plus1 then  // ascending                       
         then
         begin
            Temporary := data[ Position_2 ];
            data[ Position_2 ] := data[ Position_2 + 1 ];
            data[ Position_2 + 1 ] := Temporary;
         end;
      end;
   end;
   For i :=1 to ListBoxSP.Items.Count
         do
         begin
           data[i].xrank := IntToStr(i);
         end;
   for Position_1 := 1 to ListBoxSP.Items.Count-1 do //Length(data) - 1 do
   begin
      for Position_2 := 1 to ListBoxSP.Items.Count-2 do //( Length( data ) - 2 ) do
      begin
         P2 := StrToFloat(data[ Position_2 ].y);
         P2plus1 := StrToFloat(data[ Position_2 + 1 ].y );
         if  P2 > P2plus1 then  // ascending
         begin
            Temporary := data[ Position_2 ];
            data[ Position_2 ] := data[ Position_2 + 1 ];
            data[ Position_2 + 1 ] := Temporary;
         end;
      end;
   end;
   For i :=1 to ListBoxSP.Items.Count
         do
         begin
           data[i].yrank := IntToStr(i);
         end;
   For i:=1 to ListBoxSP.Items.Count   //This calculates the d values
         do
         begin
          data[i].d := FloatToStr(StrToFloat(data[i].xrank)-StrToFloat(data[i].yrank));
         end;
   For i:=1 to ListBoxSP.Items.Count
         do
         begin
          data[i].d2 := data[i].d;                     
          q:= sqr(StrToFloat(data[i].d2));               
          data[i].d2 := FloatToStr(q);
         end;
end;
```

Comment: The second algorithm provided in https://wiki.freepascal.org/Ranking_vectors_of_data may be helpful. It addresses potential ties.